# Data structure to control the next step

Tags: python, algorithm

I am learning coroutine

```
class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = Queue() # a queue of tasks that are ready to run.
        self.taskmap = {} #dictionary that keeps track of all active tasks (each task has a unique integer task ID)

    def new(self, target): #introduce a new task to the scheduler
        newtask = Task(target)
        self.taskmap[newtask.tid] = newtask
        self.schedule(newtask)
        return newtask.tid

    def schedule(self, task):
        self.ready.put(task)

    def mainloop(self):
        while self.taskmap: #does not remove element from taskmap
            task = self.ready.get() self.ready
            result = task.run()
            self.schedule(task)
```

When reading the `task = self.ready.get()` in schedule, I suddenly realize that the nature of data structure is about control, to control the next step, while the nature of algorithm is also about control, to control all the steps.

Does the understanding make sense?

Comment: Your question (or whatever you're trying to convey) is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Queue` object defines control of what step is next, yes. It's FIFO, as described [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html)

Here, it looks like you're just trying to keep track of tasks, whether there are any remaining, which are executing, and so on. This is "controlling all the steps." Yes.

What's unclear is the purpose. The data structure and algorithm should be suited to your purpose. `asyncio` can help you implement parallelism and event-driven designs, for example. Sometimes the goal is to quickly and efficiently render data from a source into a data structure. What you're getting at is more meaningful (to me, at least) in the context of an end goal.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your guide. Could you (very shy) introduce a book you have read to learn algorithms and data structure.

Comment: Nothing to be shy about. Data Structures and Algorithms in Python by Goodrich et al is my personal favorite Python textbook (no affiliation.)

Comment: thank you. I am reading the book from last Saturday, lol. I am excited to know that data structure and algorithms are just of two sides of an identical object.

Comment: I'm not sure what book from last Saturday you mean, but I'm excited for you and your new learning. Good luck